# print a string in python left justified with an offset

Tags: python, string-formatting

I am using Python 2.4.  I would like to print a string left justified but with an "offset".  By that I mean, print a string with a set number of spaces before it.

Example:

Print string "Hello" in a space of width 20, left justified, but five spaces inserted before the string.

```
"     Hello          "   #(The string has 5 spaces prior, and 10 space after)

print "Hello".ljust(20) #does not cut it.
```

I could use the following as a workaround:

```
print "     ", "Hello".ljust(15)
```

Is there a better approach than printing a string of 5 spaces.

Thank you,
Ahmed.

Answer (score 9):

Not really.

```
>>> '     %-15s' % ('Hello',)
'     Hello          '
```

Comment: Any particular reason for `%('Hello',)` instead of just `%("Hello")`?

Comment: @mgilson: Force of habit. Both will work for non-tuple values.

Comment: @mgilson `('hello',)` is a tuple of 1 element; `('hello')` is a string.

Comment: @Maxy-B -- I realize that.  In string formatting though, you only need a tuple if you pass multiple items to be formatted.